# What is licensing version of automation anywhere

Tags: automation, automationanywhere

Sorry if it is not relevant to this forum. 
Any idea about license cost estimation of RPA tool automation anywhere. Like x usd per robot

Answer (score 0):

AA(Automation Anywhere)Studio is for Developers for building Automation Solutions.AA Runtime is responsible for executing deployment packages on User machines.coming to licensing both studio and Runtime carries licensing costs.